# Calculating difference between points in vector

Tags: r, performance, function

I'm trying to calculate the difference between all points in a vector of length 10605 in R. For example, I am trying to do this:

```
for (i in 1:10605){
   for (j in 1:10605){
     differences[i] = housedata$Mean_household_income[i] - housedata$Mean_household_income[j]
  }
}
```

It is taking so long to compute, and I'm thinking there's a more timely way to calculate the difference between all the points with each other in this vector. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the `dist` function should do that. Distance matrices are only lower triangular because `distance(x,y) == distance(y,x)`:

```
 my.distances <- dist(housedata$Mean_household_income,
                      housedata$Mean_household_income)
```

It's going to be faster since it's done in C code. Just type:

```
dist
```

Comment: Oops wanted to comment. Edited it instead. Sorry!. dist only takes in one input. So I think it should be `dist(as.matrix(houssedata$Mean_household_income,ncol=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through an incrementally shifted/wrapped copy of the vector and subtract the two vectors. You still have to loop through the length of the data once and shift and subtract the vector each time, but it will probably save some time.

Here is an example:

```
# make a shift/wrap function
shift <- function(df,offset){
  df[((1:length(df))-1-offset)%%length(df)+1]
}

# make some data
data <- seq(1,4)

# make an empty vector to hold the data
difs = vector()

# loop through the data
for(i in 1:length(data)){
  shifted <- shift(data,i)
  result <- data - shifted
  difs <- c(difs, result)
}

print(difs)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `outer`? It uses a vectorized function (here `-`) on all combinations of two vectors and stores the results in a matrix.

For example,

```
x <- runif(10605)

system.time(
  differences <- outer(x, x, '-')
)
```

takes one second on my computer.